# How to install bluetooth that has a GUI with it

Tags: bluetooth

Just looking to install bluetooth on Linux...

I have this blueman thing installed I launch it from the menu thing I have at the bottom of my screen and nothing appears.

If anyone has a bluetooth package that comes with a GUI so I can actually see what devices are connected and if bluetooth is enabled that would be great.

I have a custom interface on Ubuntu 20. KDE Plasma. Theres no top menu. Bottom menu is apple style.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. This really sounds more like a rant than a question. You do not provide us with any info to help you. Bluetooth works out of the box on my Kubuntu 21.04 with my headpset and occasionally a keyboard. There is also an icon on the panel. I do not know what kind of GUI one would want to use a headset...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a rant, and not a specific question.

Comment: I have no GUI or icon for bluetooth my ui is the KDE plasma it looks like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=images+kde+plasma&client=ms-android-sprint-mvno-us&prmd=insv&sxsrf=ALeKk02lDa014GpORVye6HMjG8aAGZJM8Q:1620929390488&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigiprEoMfwAhVNj54KHXcaBosQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=360&bih=512&dpr=2#imgrc=veSU9atruh05ZM&imgdii=JdEWoIn4EIqrAM

Comment: I have no top menu bar is that where bluetooth normally appears for you? I was hoping for an actual application that runs a gui. I made it less ranty... Had spent a whole day trying to figure it out...

Comment: What happens when you go to system settings --> bluetooth

Comment: By the way, I assume you use KDE on Ubuntu (which is the same as using KDE) and not some "custom interface". I have a sidebar on Kubuntu. KDE is very versatile with regard to looks. The bluetooth indicator is part of the system tray  applet, which is normally located on a panel.

Comment: Sorry, the second KDE in the previous comment should read Kubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the standard KDE Bluetooth settings look like. The first
picture is the expanded Bluetooth applet in the panel. By default it is only visible when Bluetooth is enabled, but this can be toggled by right-click on the system tray applet.
[image]

This is how the Bluetooth settings look in the KDE Settings:
[image]

If you do not see these settings, maybe your Bluetooth hardware is not recognized. solving this might indeed need a bit of terminal work, since unfortunately not all manufacturers provide drivers for GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time here... this is where I am at right... so I ordered a bluetooth usb adapter called MPOW that supposedly supported Linux. I find out that there's some issue and I need to upgrade my kernel. I upgrade the kernel but then it wont load because its not signed. I go to turn of Secure Boot and then the damn thing doesn't boot. I then find some patch and put that in and the dang thing still doesn't work.

Comment: My whole assumption was that Linux would display a bluetooth menu option even without a device... because I've installed damn near all the bluetooth packages. I'm so surprised it wouldn't show a bluetooth panel and then INSIDE the menu panel say no devices supported or whatever. I guess it won't appear in the system settings menu until I have supported hardware???

Comment: Here's my desktop by the way... wow it was hard to get Xinerama to work xD https://pasteboard.co/K1Kn6g6.png

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Add a panel, so that you can add the bluetooth applet to it.